# How to change mesh to Flat or Smooth shading while in sculpt mode?

Tags: shaders, sculpting, sculpt

I am learning sculpt mode and the best way to see the results is by switching from flat to smooth shading in object mode, but the best way to see geometry of what i am doing is best viewed with flat shading. Is there a hot key to toggle flat or smooth shading without having to switch from object to sculpt mode each time?

Answer (score 1):

Only way I know is press your space bar and look for flat and click on shade flat while in sculpt mode. Do the same for switching to smooth.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: What if you set spacebar to "play animation". How to get in the menu you're talking about then?

Comment: @ChristophWerner Go to edit > preferences > keymap > click "Name" and search for "search" (without quotations) to find the hotkey for your search menu. Here's a screenshot of what that looks like: https://imgur.com/a/iEbikqZ

Comment: OK. You mean I have to use the search menu, that is found on the F3 key to search for the "flat" function in sculpting mode? I thought there's a tools menu for sculpting which appears, when pressing a key.

Answer (score -2):

Using the shift key will cause some sculpt brushes to smooth.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is about shading not about sculpting brushes.